# Setting up GraphQL.net

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql.net

Cannot get this to run. I get the following error message, I have made it as simple as possible but what required service am I missing.

I am using the Graph Type first approach.
https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/introduction

> System.InvalidOperationException: Required service for type
> autumn.TestOGT not found    at
> GraphQL.Utilities.ServiceProviderExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType) in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Utilities/ServiceProviderExtensions.cs:line 33    at
> GraphQL.Types.SchemaTypes.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<.ctor>b__2(Type t) in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Types/Collections/SchemaTypes.cs:line 141    at
> GraphQL.Types.SchemaTypes.AddTypeIfNotRegistered(Type type,
> TypeCollectionContext context) in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Types/Collections/SchemaTypes.cs:line 539    at
> GraphQL.Types.SchemaTypes.HandleField(IComplexGraphType parentType,
> FieldType field, TypeCollectionContext context, Boolean
> applyNameConverter) in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Types/Collections/SchemaTypes.cs:line 429    at
> GraphQL.Types.SchemaTypes.AddType(IGraphType type,
> TypeCollectionContext context) in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Types/Collections/SchemaTypes.cs:line 333    at
> GraphQL.Types.SchemaTypes..ctor(ISchema schema, IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider) in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Types/Collections/SchemaTypes.cs:line 154    at
> GraphQL.Types.Schema.CreateSchemaTypes() in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Types/Schema.cs:line 328    at
> GraphQL.Types.Schema.Initialize() in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Types/Schema.cs:line 102    at
> GraphQL.Utilities.SchemaPrinter.PrintFilteredSchema(Func`2 directiveFilter, Func`2 typeFilter) in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Utilities/SchemaPrinter.cs:line 79    at
> GraphQL.Utilities.SchemaPrinter.Print() in
> /*/src/GraphQL/Utilities/SchemaPrinter.cs:line 63    at
> Autumn.Api.Controllers.AutumnController.Schema() in
> C:\ws\Autumn-APICore\Autumn.Api\Controllers\AutumnController.cs:line
> 37    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)

```
using GraphQL.Types;
using System;
        
namespace autumn
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int Number { get; set; } = 5;
        public string String { get; set; } = "Test Class";
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; } = System.DateTime.Now;
    }
        
    public class TestOGT : ObjectGraphType<Test>
    {
        public TestOGT()
        {
            Field(x => x.Number, nullable: true).Name("Number");
            Field(x => x.String, nullable: true).Name("String");
            Field(x => x.DateTime, nullable: true).Name("DateTime");
        }
    }
        
    public class AutumnQuery : ObjectGraphType
    {        
        public AutumnQuery()
        {
            Field<TestOGT>("Article",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(
                    new QueryArgument<StringGraphType> { Name = "Language", DefaultValue="en-us" },
                    new QueryArgument<StringGraphType> { Name = "Id" }
                ),
                resolve: context => { return new Test(); });
        }
        
    }
    public class AutumnSchema : Schema
    {
        public AutumnSchema(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, AutumnQuery query) : base(serviceProvider)
        {
            this.Query = query;
        }
    }
   
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AutumnController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        private readonly AutumnSchema _schema;
        
        public AutumnController(ISchema schema)
        {
            _schema = (AutumnSchema)schema;
        }
        
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/schema")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Schema()
        {
            return Content(new SchemaPrinter(_schema).Print());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is AutumnQuery is not needed and had int the constructor IServiceProvider